# Where to find default system icons in Nativescript?

Tags: android, icons, nativescript

I have created an empty Nativescript application with `tns create myApp'. However,`app/App_Resources/Android/drawable-hdpi` and other directories does not contain any default system icons. Thus, I cannot use them in the application. How can I find or install default system icons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

However, the default system icons are called using something like this:

`<ActionItem ios:systemIcon="12" android:systemIcon="ic_menu_search" tap="showSearch" ios:position="right" android:position="actionBar" />`

You can find a list (unfortunately without images) at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.drawable.html

Comment: How about `ios.systemIcon`? And it seems the android ones are the `ic_` prefixed ones here - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.drawable.html - but when i use them they are always transparent in the middle, and just border, any way to get them solid colored?

Answer (score 2):

For using your custom icons in the application, you have to add them in each `drawable-XXX` folder and then in your XML `src="res://my_icon"`

You can find more informations in the official documentation of NS : https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/ui-images#load-images-from-resource

Comment: How about `ios.systemIcon`?